# Index count being wrapped into the data as one object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First time on stackoverflow so bear with me. Code is below. Basically, the df_history is a dataframe with different variables. I am trying to pull the 'close' variable and sort it based on the categorical type of the currency.

When I pull data over using the .query command, it gives me 1 object with all the individual observations together separated by a space. I know how to separate that back into independent data, but issue is that it is pulling the index count with the observations. In the image you can see 179, 178, 177 etc in the BTC object. I dont want that there and didnt indend to pull it. How do I get rid of that?

```
additional_rows = []
for currency in selected_coins:
      df_history = df_history.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True) 
      row_data = [currency,
          df_history.query('granularity == \'daily\' and currency == @currency')['close'], 
          df_history.query('granularity == \'daily\' and currency == @currency').head(180)['close'].pct_change(),
          df_history['date']
          ]
      additional_rows.append(row_data)
df_additional_info = pd.DataFrame(additional_rows, columns = ['currency',
                                                              'close',
                                                              'returns',
                                                              'df_history'])
df_additional_info.set_index('currency').transpose()
```

[image: Output]

```
import ast
list_of_lists = df_additional_info.close.to_list()
flat_list = [i for sublist in list_of_lists for i in ast.literal_eval(sublist)]
uniq_list = list(set(flat_list))
len(uniq_list),len(flat_list)
```

[image: Output]

I was trying to pull data from one data frame to the next and sort it based on a categorical input from the currency variable. It is not transferring over well